# how to get if file modification date is older than N days [batch script]

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I got one problem that i want to solve basically i want to delete file that exist for 2 day or more than 2 day and i want to know if it exist or not to be delete because i need to record in the Log.txt if the file been deleted or not

this is current code without the Log.txt

```
forfiles /p "E:\Backup\DailyWinflexBackup" /s /d -2 /c "cmd /c del @file : date >= 2 days >NUL"
```

i want to do the statement like this

```
IF (FILE WITH MORE THAN 2 days exist) (

::PROCESS DELETE
ECHO (MESSAGE)>>Log.txt
) ELSE (
ECHO (MESSAGE)>>Log.txt
)
```

Comment: What do you expect your current code to do? the part behind `/C` is not a valid command line...

Comment: what do you mean not a valid command line?

Comment: `cmd /c del @file : date >= 2 days >NUL` is not valid syntax of Windows command prompt (`cmd`); the `:` and everything after is not understood...

Comment: so the correct code is like this? forfiles /p "E:\Backup\DailyWinflexBackup" /s /m *.* -d -2 -c "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: Seems fine (although I would use `/` for all options consistently); but this just deletes files without any log message; you could extend it like this: `forfiles /S /P "E:\Backup\DailyWinflexBackup" /D -2 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path && echo @file deleted"` to have a log message returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I assume you want different log messages to be output in case a file has been deleted or not. For this you could use two nested [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) loops, like in the following example:

```cmd
> nul forfiles /S /P "E:\Backup\DailyWinflexBackup" /M "*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M @file /D -155 /C 0x22cmd /C del @path && > con echo 00x7840file deleted0x22 || > con echo @file NOT deleted"
```

The outer `forfiles` loop enumerates all matching files, not regarding their age (or last modification date). The query [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)`@isdir==FALSE` ensures that only files are handled, because `forfiles` also enumerates directories. The inner `forfiles` loop matches one item per iteration of the outer loop, and filters it by age (due to `/D -2`); if last modified 2 days ago or earlier, the file is deleted by [`del`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) and a related log message is output by [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html); if the file is younger, `forfiles` fails (the [`2> nul`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) part suppresses its error message), and therefore, the `echo` command behind [`||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) becomes executed. The [`> nul`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) part at the very beginning suppresses empty lines returned by `forfiles`. Due to that, explicit redirection to the console, [`> con`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is needed for the `echo` outputs not to become suppressed too. To write the log messages to a log file, replace `> con` by something like `> "\path\to\log\file.txt"`.